# Google Maps API - Map not showing at times during day

Tags: google-maps

We've got a custom map on this website where we pin 3 locations: https://finishingtouchplus.com/

I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure out why the map is only displayed in the afternoon.   Originally, we were using my developer's API.  Thinking that maybe it was maxing out on impressions had he used that API on other sites too,  we created a new API and can confirm that it's not limiting out on impressions.

Consistently every single day... the map does not work in the morning and does work in the afternoon.  Since it's working in the afternoon, we've ascertained it's not a coding issue.  Problem is across all browsers and devices.

Any thoughts?

Grateful in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Got it figured out.  We were using GEOCODE to find lat and long to pin addresses.  THAT was maxing out on limits.

Man...a lot of hours spent to solve what was a simple problem.